# Discord.py adding params to a api command

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am needing help in adding parameters in API command for api's such Urban Dictionary (for searching definitions) and open weather map (to get weather of certain location) I understand the fact that a lot of these are provided with code for querystring then ("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) but I don't understand how to allow something such as $urban yo-yo.

```
@commands.command(
        name="urban",
        description="Allows the user to get a definition from Urban Dictionary",
        aliases=['urbandict']
    )
    async def urban(self, ctx):
        url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"

        headers = {
            'x-rapidapi-key': self.bot.quote_api_key,
            'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com"
        }

        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
                r = await response.json()
                # print(r)
                embed = discord.Embed(title="Term:", description=f"{r['']}")

                embed.add_field(name="Definition:", value=f"||{r['']}||")

                embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [`Urban Dictionnary API`](https://rapidapi.com/community/api/urban-dictionary), `querystring` must a dictionnary that has a `term` key.
Then, to add parameters to commands, you simply have to add a parameter to your function and `discord.py` will parse the command automatically. If you want everything after `$urban` in a single parameter, you have to add a `*` before the `term` parameter.

It would look like this :

```py
@commands.command()
async def urban(self, ctx, *, term):
    url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"

    querystring = {"term": term}
    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': self.bot.quote_api_key,
        'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com"
    }

    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring) as response:
            r = await response.json()

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Term:", description=f"{r['']}")
    embed.add_field(name="Definition:", value=f"||{r['']}||")
    embed.set_author(name=ctx.author.display_name, icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

For the Open Weather Map API, you need to pass the argument in the url. For instance, if you want Paris' 5 days forecast, you'd have to use this url :

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Paris&units=metric&APPID=your_token
```

For more informations, you can look at the documentations :

- [Discord.py's command arguments handler](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters)
- [Urban Dictionnary API](https://rapidapi.com/community/api/urban-dictionary)
- [Open Weather Map API](https://www.meteomatics.com/en/api/getting-started/?gclid=CjwKCAiAudD_BRBXEiwAudakX5hOIl8ZHytyVsijYXLwLp9q5N9iUNs5RqUtNKnEHT4nBCkALf6ocBoCJYMQAvD_BwE)

Comment: I truly appreciate your help for all of this just one more issue, I am trying to pass the results through the embed as you can see but what it gets is a embed cant be over 2048 characters, I've already tried passing list to definition through f"{r['list']['definition']}" but then it gets TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Looking at the API, `r['list']` is a list of definitions so you need to specify an index. For instance, if you'd want the first definition, you'd have to type `r['list'][0]['definition']`